# How to use tensorflow hub layer embedding in convolutional layer for text?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-hub

I am new to the TensorFlow hub and I am trying to use the hub embedding layer in my Conv1D network for text classification purposes.

I don't have any issue with using the hub embedding layer in sequential model:

```
hub_layer = hub.KerasLayer("https://tfhub.dev/google/nnlm-en-dim50/2", 
input_shape=[], dtype=tf.string, trainable=False)

model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(hub_layer)
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(128))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Activation('relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(5))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Activation('softmax'))

model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer="adam", metrics=["accuracy"])
model.summary()
```

However, I am not able to use in Conv1D model:

First model:

```
int_sequences_input = Input(shape=(max_length,))
embedded_sequences = hub_layer(int_sequences_input)
x = layers.Conv1D(128, 5, activation="relu")(embedded_sequences)
x = layers.MaxPooling1D(5)(x)
x = layers.Conv1D(128, 5, activation="relu")(x)
x = layers.GlobalMaxPooling1D()(x)
x = layers.Dense(128, activation="relu")(x)
x = layers.Dropout(0.5)(x)
preds = layers.Dense(len(class_names), activation="softmax")(x)
model = keras.Model(int_sequences_input, preds)
model.summary()
```

or:

Second model:

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(hub_layer)
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(128, 7, activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.GlobalMaxPooling1D())
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()
```

As I am getting value error as:

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer conv1d_11 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: [None, 50]
```

I would like to know if there is any solution to this?
I looked into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62252267/how-to-chain-an-input-layer-to-tensorflow-hub) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62545134/how-to-use-embedding-models-in-tensorflow-hub-with-lstm-layer), but none of them solve my issue.

Answer (score 1):

The resulting embedding dimensions are: `(num_examples, embedding_dimension)` which is not compatible with 1D convolution as it expects 3D input.

Try to reshape after hub layer, like this:

```
model.add(hub_layer)
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Reshape((1,50)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(16, 3, activation='relu', padding = 'same'))
...
```

Comment: thanks for the comments. Is there any chance that we can apply to the first above Conv1D  model with ```int_sequences_input .....``` ?

Comment: You need to apply embedding first otherwise it is not that meaningful as now.

Comment: Do you mean like first ```hub layer``` then ```int_sequences_input```. Can you please provide a code example? thanks

Comment: I meant embedding layer should be your first layer, it does not make sense to start with convolution and then continue with embedding after all. Correct me if I misunderstood you.